# Forcing jqGrid to get values from database on click of a hyperlink (anchor tag)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

Is there a way in which I can force the jqGrid to get the data again from the database by clicking on a hyperlink which is say, "Get Data Again" ??

While at it, does reloading the grid using the `.reload()` function force the grid to get the new values? I am asking since the action method that's supposed to get values from the DB was not invoked. (No breakpoints were hit.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to this:

```
<a id="yourId" title="Get Data Again" href="#" onclick="reloadGrid();return false;">Get Data Again</a>
```

And, in your `reloadGrid()` javascript method:

```
function reloadGrid(){
    $("#yourGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");  
}
```

The `.trigger("reloadGrid")` will reload the grid and, consequently, the action method on your controller.